# Reapply constraints after hiding UITabBar

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIButton` that is constrained to the view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide` bottom anchor and a `UITabBar` in that `UIView`. Everything is okay there. However, when I fullscreen an image, I hide the `UITabBar`. When I dismiss the fullscreen, I show the `UITabBar` again. However, the `UIButton` moves down and doesn't constrain to the `UITabBar` as it did before the `UITabBar` was hidden. The `UIButton` is covered partially by the `UITabBar`. Any solutions?

Here is the dismiss fullscreen code.

```
@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two things you can try:

**Solution 1:**

Add this line to `dismissFullscreenImage():`

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

This invalidates the layout of `self.view` and causes it to be laid out again.

---

**Solution 2:**

You can avoid the need to relayout the view by making the `navigationBar` and `tabBar` invisible.

Instead of hiding/showing the `navigationBar` and `tabBar` by changing their `isHidden` properties, try setting their `alpha` values:

```
// hide
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 0

// show
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 1
```